# How to show ink level of printer in linux

Tags: linux, printer, canon-pixma

I have installed ink program but it cannot detect my canon printer. What should I do? My printer is connected via usb and yet it's not found. I was able to print with it but I have no idea how to see the ink levels.

Comment: Most "ink level" programs are just broad estimates based on time and number of pages. Looking at the ink cartridges gives a far better idea of what's left.

Comment: Don't worry about it: the printer will stop when it thinks it's out of ink. Then replace the cartridge. Many printer monitoring apps are no more than bloatware.

Answer (score 2):

my printer is Canon E410, and i'm using Linux Mint. I installed ink, sudo apt install ink. the command is;

$ink -p usb

ink 0.5.3 (c) 2018 Markus Heinz

Canon E410 series

Black:                                  40%
Color:                                  60%